# Updating TextView inside Header ListView

Tags: android, listview, getview

I'm trying to update my `TextView` when my `onItenClick` event fires, I have several TextViews, they are created as many I want inside my row template, but here goes the problem, when I try to set this `TextView` value it's acctually getting setted, but another textview, is also setted, with the same value I have on idea of the why to this behavior, but have no idea how to fix it.

My idea:

- I my `getRowView` method (when I scroll the list), I'm seeing an
  unusual behavior, once after I set some value to one of my itens, it
  keep changing the text view that got this value. So I think here is
  the core of the problem.

PS: I'm using the component [HeaderListView](http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/), if you get another suggestion of framework to do the same thing, I would really appreciate.

PS2: Here goes my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.soutsapp.souts.R;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.model.Menu;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.model.Product;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.model.modelview.OrderItem;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.userInterface.activity.SectionAdapter;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.userInterface.adapter.HeaderListView;

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
private Context mContext;
private List<OrderItem> itens;

private Menu menu;
public MenuFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    mContext = getContext();

    itens = new ArrayList<>();
    menu = new Menu();

    final String[] sec1 = {"aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa"};
    final String[] sec2 = {"bbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbb"};
    final String[] sec3 = {"cccccccc","cccccccc","cccccccc","cccccccc","cccccccc","cccccccc","cccccccc"};
    final String[] sec4 = {"dddddddd","dddddddd","dddddddd","dddddddd","dddddddd","dddddddd","dddddddd"};

    HeaderListView lv = (HeaderListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_menu_items);

    lv.setAdapter(new SectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public int numberOfSections() {
            return menu.getMenuSessions().size();
        }

        @Override
        public int numberOfRows(int section) {
            return menu.getMenuSessions().get(section).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getRowItem(int section, int row) {
            return menu.getMenuSessions().get(section).get(row);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasSectionHeaderView(int section) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getRowView(int section, int row, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(getResources().getLayout(R.layout.menu_item_row), null);
            }

            //Product product = (Product)getRowItem(section, row);
            //convertView.setId(product.getId());

            TextView tvMenuItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_menu_item_name);
            TextView tvMenuItemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);

            String itemName = ((Product)getRowItem(section,row)).getName();
            tvMenuItemName.setText(itemName);

            String itemPrice = String.valueOf(((Product) getRowItem(section, row)).getPrice());
            tvMenuItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);

            final int mySection = section;
            final int myRow = row;

            final TextView tvQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_quantity);
            tvQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Product product = (Product) getRowItem(mySection, myRow);

                    if (tvQuantity.getText().equals("1") && !tvQuantity.getText().equals("")){
                        tvQuantity.setText("");

                        OrderItem itenToRemove = null;
                        for(OrderItem item: itens){
                            if(item.getProductId() == product.getId()){
                                itenToRemove = item;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        itens.remove(itenToRemove);
                    }
                    else{

                        for(OrderItem item: itens){
                            if(item.getProductId() == product.getId()){
                                int quantity = item.getQuantity();
                                item.setQuantity(--quantity);
                                tvQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSectionHeaderItemViewType(int section) {
            return section % 1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = (TextView)  getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(getResources().getLayout(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1), null);
            }

            if (getSectionHeaderItemViewType(section) == 0) {
                ((TextView) convertView).setText("Header for section " + section);
            } else {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("Header for section " + section);
            }

            switch (section) {
                case 0:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue_Jay));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red_Wine));
                    break;
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section, int row, long id) {
            super.onRowItemClick(parent, view, section, row, id);

            //Product p = (Product)view.getTag();

            TextView tvQuantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_quantity);

            Product p = menu.getMenuSessions().get(section).get(row);
            //Product p = (Product) getRowItem(section, row);

            boolean exist = false;
            for(OrderItem item : itens){
                if(item.getProductId() == p.getId()){
                    int actualQuantity = item.getQuantity();
                    item.setQuantity(++actualQuantity);
                    tvQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
                    exist = true;
                }
            }
            if(!exist){
                itens.add(new OrderItem(p.getId(), 1));
                tvQuantity.setText("1");
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

Here goes on screenshot, I had touch the "Smirnoff dose" item, and both "Smirnoff dose" and "Água" have their textviews values changed.

[image]

Comment: If the convertview reference never changes it's possible you're referencing the same TV even if it appears twice? Have you tried using the ViewHolder model for this?

Comment: @McAdam331 No I didn't, if I use a ViewHolder how it would help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Well my hunch is that when you call `tvQuantity.setText()` that TextView is being referenced in multiple places so if you used a ViewHolder it may help ensure that there aren't conflicting references. I'm not quite sure that's true here though now that I think about it.  Can you post a screenshot so I can see what you meant by two of them being set?

Comment: @McAdam331 I had added one screenshot and a brief explanation

Comment: hm that is very weird

Comment: @McAdam331 yeah, it is! It seems that the getView is messing the text view that sould be updated